# Trouble creating an xpath to be able to locate elements conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I have been trying to create an xpath supposed to locate the first three `Yes` within `p` elements until the text `Demarcation` within `h1` elements. The existing one which I've used within the below script locates all the text within `p` elements. However, I can't find any idea to move along. Just consider the one I've created already to be a placeholder.

***How can I create an xapth to be able to locate first three `Yes` within `p` elements and nothing else?***

My attempt so far:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

htmldoc="""
<li>
    <a>Nope</a>
    <a>Nope</a>
    <p>Yes</p>
    <p>Yes</p>
    <p>Yes</p>
    <h1>Demarcation</h1>
    <p>No</p>
    <p>No</p>
    <h1>Not this</h2>
    <p>No</p>
    <p>Not this</p>
</li>
"""
root = fromstring(htmldoc)
for item in root.xpath("//li/p"):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below to select paragraphs that are preceding siblings of header `"Demarcation"`

```
//li/p[following-sibling::h1[.="Demarcation"]]
```

Comment: I was eagerly expecting any answer from you @sir Andersson. It did the trick. I'm very much enthusiastic to learn how to do the same using `preceding` sibling? I can't give you the link (as I can't remeber where is it) but I clearly recall that you did something once using `preceding` sibling in similar cases. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @robots.txt , the same with `preceding-sibling` axis would look like `//li/h1[.="Demarcation"]/preceding-sibling::p`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to depend on the `h1` tag containing `Demarcation`, so start from it:

```
//h1[contains(., "Demarcation")]/preceding-sibling::p[contains(., "Yes")][position()<4]
```

The idea is to get previous `p` elements and I added the `position()<4` so you only get three, you can remove that if you just need all of the `p`:

```
//h1[contains(., "Demarcation")]/preceding-sibling::p[contains(., "Yes")]
```

Comment: I believe the values of target paragraphs are unknown. Otherwise they can be selected simply with `//p[.="Yes"]`...

Comment: well, that wasn't specified correctly on your question, and you could just remove that part of course to just `p`.